# Proving $A \subset B \Rightarrow B' \subset A'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that A is a subset of B. How can we show that B-complement is a subset of A-complement?

Comment: tried specific exmaples, but couldn't find a general solution.

Comment: A belongs to? Maybe you mean subset?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $b\in B^c$. Is it possible that $b\in A$? Suppose it is, and derive a contradiction, and you should have your desired containment.

Comment: no, because A belongs to B, but b belongs to B-complement. How did you write with math notations?

Comment: This site uses TeX markup, my specific code is `$b\in B^c$` and `$b\in A$`. To get them to look the way they do, surround them with $ signs. Here is a [good list of basic symbols](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a proof by contradiction, $b\in B^c \implies b \notin A$ since $A \subset B$ hence $b \in A^c$ which implies the result.

The key here being that for all $x$, either $x\in X$ or $x\in X^c$.